MS Access db VBA function not recognizing value of passed parameter
I have an accdb that was working fine for years and we somehow messed something up.  We have a form. It has a button. It calls a function of vba code. The code displays messages, run queries that create a table and finally CALL ANOTHER function that open an Excel file from a shared drive location, refreshes the pivots and saves the file to another share location.
This has worked flawless for 15 years. Suddenly it fails on the call to refresh sheets. REFRESHSHEETS is passed two paramters: TemplateBook and NewBook. It does not seem to know the values for these parameters.
The module opens with this:
Option Compare Database
Public TemplateBook As String
Public NewBook As String
Option Explicit

The form button calls this:
Private Sub Command178_Click()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim STYLE As Variant
Dim response As Integer
STYLE = vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton2
MsgBox "Refreshing Report and wrinting to X drive..."
TemplateBook = "G:\ReportTemplates\TeleDOMdata.xls"
NewBook = "X:\Reports\MISC\TeleDOMdata.xls"
RefreshSheets
MsgBox "Done! "
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
End Sub

The REFRESHSHEETS has this code:
Function RefreshSheets()
 Dim xcelapp As Object
 Dim pc As Object
 Dim wks As Object
 Dim qt As Object
'Delete Existing Report
If Dir(NewBook) = "" Then
'Do Nothing
Else
Kill NewBook
Call Timr(10)   'waits 10 secs
End If

 Set xcelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xcelapp.Workbooks.Open TemplateBook
xcelapp.DisplayAlerts = False
'Refresh All Workbook Sheets
 xcelapp.activeworkbook.refreshall
 'Force a pause here
 Call Timr(10)   'waits 10 secs
'Save to appropriate location
 xcelapp.activeworkbook.SaveAs FileName:=NewBook
 Call Timr(10)   'waits 10 secs
xcelapp.activeworkbook.Close
Set xcelapp = Nothing      'nessecary to prevent hanging Excelprocesses on your machine
End Function

This worked fine for years. We have numerous form buttons similar that no longer work. We have another db that performs similar tasks---it works fine. Something got messed up in this db.
Here is the error:

Run-Time error '53' File not found:

Click Debug: Kill (NewBook) is highlighted.
If I comment out:
If Dir(NewBook) = "" Then
'Do Nothing
Else
Kill NewBook
Call Timr(10)   'waits 10 secs
End If

then it simply fails on the first occurrence of where templatebook is referenced.
IF I COPY:
TemplateBook = "G:\ReportTemplates\TeleDOMdata.xls"
NewBook = "X:\Reports\MISC\TeleDOMdata.xls"

INTO the REFRESHEETS function..it works fine. It seems that somehow the parameter values for NewBook and TemplateBook are not being passed.
Ideas?
not sure what to do...

If TemplateBook and NewBook paths don't change, they should be constants.

In the VBA editor, go to the function RefreshSheets, click on the variable TemplateBook and press [Shift]+[F2]. Does the editor jump to the declaration of the variable in the module where Command178_Click lives? You might have another declaration somewhere else in you code. However, if I where you, I would pass the file names as parameter instead of using global variables.

Does the code compile? What debugging have you done? Set breakpoint and step through code. What is Timr(10) - is that a typo? Really should give controls more meaningful names than the Access defaults.

To expand on what @FunThomas recommended... Update your Function RefreshSheets() to Function RefreshSheets(templatePath As String, newBookPath As String) and call it like RefreshSheets("G:\ReportTemplates\TeleDOMdata.xls", "X:\Reports\MISC\TeleDOMdata.xls")   That method doesn't return anything, so it should really be a Sub and not a Function.

Also - you call Set xcelapp = Nothing but before that you really need to call xcelapp.Quit   Setting the variable to Nothing doesn't close Excel.

Thanks all but none of this helped. I can remove the timr function it is of no consequence.

NewBook and templateBook do change depending on the reports being refreshed. I do not want to mess with the refreshsheets function as it works fine in other accdbs.
The issue is the buttom function on the form has this vba: NewBook = "X:\LVPG\Reports\PhysicianHealthNetwork\Report1.xlsx". The X:\LVPG......is not being passed to the refreshsheets function called.
It no longer works on any of the buttons.

...yet the same sort of thing works in another accdb...yet I can see any difference in the modules between the dbs. Perhaps the form is corrupted..and the Compact and Repair is not fixing something?

Finally....if I create a new blank form, add a button, then copy the vba for the button from the other form....IT WORKS!!!!
However the form has 20 buttons each with its own VBA code...so unless I can somehow create a NEW form and bring over all the buttons and their code without manually doing that..I am stuck.

Solution: I had to delete and rebuild the form and all buttons. I was able to copy VBA code from a backup for each button.  Now all is working.  Some sort of software bug must have been in place.
